# How to upload file to my local Splunk and do search on that?

Tags: splunk

I recently installed Splunk Enterprise on my laptop. I have log file with log entry in the following format:

```
2016-12-06 20:59:58,773 ProductName=XYZ ActivityGUID=bb1637a2-7b82-4878-a5a0-65f02679b7b1 BusinessModel=ABC ProductType=CCB ActivityName=endpoint-v2 ActivityStep=rs TimestampStart=2016-12-06 20:59:58,767 Timestamp=2016-12-06 20:59:58,773 HostLocal=10.186.108.199 HostRemote=10.186.108.5 Username=47b460c4-0a24-4a14-8b81-73b8f2dde43c OperationName=GetProduct SupplierID=v5-e48fb7508bb3484c9aa1f00b39ddb3e5-0-0-32 RAIL=70201 TRACK=0 StatusCode=0 TimestampEnd=2016-12-06 20:59:58,773 Duration=6 DurationN=5
```

I would like to upload that file to my local Splunk and experiment with different Splunk queries. So, I added the above log entry in a .txt file and uploaded that .txt file to Splunk using file uploader and chose all the default options. I am not finding that file in search to query on it. Can you please help?

Comment: When you say you "used the file uploader," I assume you meant from the "Add data to Splunk" link from the index page.  Did the preview look correct?  Did you complete the ingest?  The last page should have offered you a 'Start Searching' button, which would lead you to a page with a base search pre-populated.  The search "source=<your_filename.txt>" should be part of that base search.

Answer (score 1):

Follow These steps to add data and run search query

[image: Click on Settings and Then Add Data]

[image: Click on Start Searching to search]